# select alias name from view is not working in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
  create view f as select 1 as "f" from dual

  select f from f
```

this is showing error how can I retrieve data using column name
[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Comment: The documentation is slightly misleading: "If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object." .... except if everything is in uppercase inside the quotes!

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the column name as `"f"`, therefore the column name will be stored in the database as `f`, rather than `F` as is the default if you hadn't put double-quotes around it.

You need to refer to the column exactly as you created it - ie. with the double-quotes around it. The double-quotes tell Oracle to pass the identifier name in exactly as typed, rather than converting everything to upper case (which is the default).

The following demonstrates how the metadata about the view columns is stored in the dictionary:

```
create or replace view f as select 1 as "f", 2 as f from dual;

select table_name, column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'F';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                   
------------------------------ ------------------------------
F                              f                             
F                              F
```

And this is why it's rarely a good idea to make your identifiers case sensitive - you will need to refer to them with double-quotes forever more. Such a pain...!